# hot to remove some part of Hover Text in plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

In Default option in *plotly's* hover text I have 3 lines of text, I want to remove two and leave just one line where it says *'count' + 'number of observations'*

This line doesn't do anything

```
mode = 'text', text = ~Count,
```

I still have 3 lines of text
thanks for any help

```
p1 <- ggplot(cancer0, 
        mode = 'text', text = ~Count, 
        aes(x = cancer10[,1], 
        fill = cancer10[,2])) + geom_bar(position = input$pos) + 
        xlab("Factor") + ylab("Count") + theme_bw()

ggplotly(p1) %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
```

Here is a screenshot of the output:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hmm.. It seems your screenshot isn't showing as expected.

Comment: Can you add some example data?

Comment: my screenshot was uploaded and when I edited my post it says I'm  new to stackoverflow and can't add any screenshots (weird)

Comment: here is how the data look like https://i.imgur.com/1juwlQg.png 
so I want to get the total number of Female and Male with particular cancer type

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Stackoverflow prefers raw data to screenshots, see here for a dicussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: From help: `tooltip = ` a character vector specifying which aesthetic mappings to show in the tooltip. The default, "all", means show all the aesthetic mappings (including the unofficial "text" aesthetic). The order of variables here will also control the order they appear. For example, use tooltip = c("y", "x", "colour") if you want y first, x second, and colour last.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution based on the `text` aesthetic:

```
cancer10 <- read.table(text="
Id Sex Count
A F 0  
A M 5
B F 7
B M 20
C F 17
C M 36
D F 22
D M 80
E F 40
E M 80", header=T)

library(ggplot2)
p1 <- ggplot(cancer10, aes(x = Id, y=Count, fill = Sex, 
        text = paste("Count:", Count))) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge") + 
        xlab("Factor") + ylab("Count") + theme_bw()

library(plotly)
ggplotly(p1, tooltip="text") %>% config(displayModeBar = F)
```

[image]

Comment: I did that; p1 <- ggplot(cancer0, aes(x = cancer10[,1], fill = cancer10[,2]),text = paste("Count:", Count))+ 
  geom_bar(position = input$pos) + 
xlab("Factor") + ylab("Count") + theme_bw()+ theme(legend.title = element_blank())
ggplotly(p1) %>% config(displayModeBar = F)

no error but nothing changed, still have 3 lines when hover over the bars

Answer (score 4):

After converting your `ggplot` to a `plotly` graph you can still change its values before displaying it.

In this case you could change the `text` attribute.

```
library(plotly)

g <- ggplot(mpg, aes(class)) + geom_bar() + theme_bw()
gp <- ggplotly(g)

for (i in 2:length(gp$x$data[[1]]$text)) {
  gp$x$data[[1]]$text[[i]] <- strsplit(gp$x$data[[1]]$text[[i]], '<br />')[[1]][[1]]
}

gp
```

All bars but the first got a new hovertext.

[image]